# how to set default location in browse tag

Tags: html, jsp, jsp-tags

Am doing project in j2ee.I use Browse button. I need to fetch images/files from a folder inside my project folder, everytime.I wish to set my project's folder name as a default location for my browse button.How to do that?

am using tis following code in a jsp page:

and calling the value in servlet :

String image= (String) request.getParameter("img");

while browsing ,the whole path is getting displayed but only the name of the image is passing as value in the sevlet.How to get the entire path? or how to set my project folder as default location while browsing?

Answer (score 1):

If this is rendering a standard

```
<input type="file".../>
```

Then ***you have no control*** over the default directory.

Using flash gains you a bit more control (filetype preset, single/multiple file selection etc.)

I'm not sure if Java Applets have more access/options, hopefully someone can advise.

PS. for the standard input tag, the browser will remember the last location you used, so you only need to navigate once, if you are uploading several files from the same directory.

Answer (score 1):

I actually solved this problem with an interesting trick. Here's how...

Create an external vbscript `include file` called `vbshelper.inc` which contains the following code:

```
function stuffKeys(x)
     Set wshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    wshShell.Sendkeys(x)
end function
```

---

Inside your HTML code header, place the following line as your first `< Script`> element...

`< Script type="text/VBScript src="vbshelper.inc">`

later, in your HTML code, create the button like this...

`< input type="File" id="srcFile" onchange="go_do_something()" onclick="stuffkeys(' C:\Temp\*.txt~')">`

Note the space before the C in `' C:\Temp*.txt~'` and the tilde `~`  after the .txt.

Comment: This works in MSIE only and then also only when the HTML runs from the local disk file system instead of being sent over HTTP. Beyond that, MSIE with the last updates will by default show security warnings.