# Set the start directory for a file upload input element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am adding a file input/upload element to a form but I want to make it easy to select the file I want the user to upload by having the file explorer open to a certain path instead of the last directory they were in last in the file explorer.

For example, suggested directory is : C:\Users\\Documents

With a simple file input element `<input type='file' />`

I do't want to force them to select a certain file, just go to a certain start directory. Setting the `value` attribute didn't work, so I'm assuming it's some other way or it is more complicated than I first anticipated.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It's not possible to do what you want, because anything file system related isn't possible with JS due to security violations. Besides, lots of users do not have a `C:\Users\\Documents` folder. Possible duplicate of [how to set default location in browse tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/397237/how-to-set-default-location-in-browse-tag)

Comment: its not possible to set a default directory for input file type as it is a security risk. also if someone is using a different OS, how would you be able to use it?

Comment: I guess that was just my example, without going into too much detail I know that anyone using this particular tool will have this suggested directory available to them and it will not change. Is it still possible?

Comment: No, you can't do it.

Comment: no, you cannot have the server dictate where a file browser should be opened. that would require the server to know the structure of the user's local drive, which would be a major security/privacy violation.

Comment: Can desktop applications do it?  I'm sure I've seen it done somwhere....

Comment: desktop applications can do whatever they want. they're already "on" the user's PC. a web application can't, especially if it was loaded up from "outside".