# How to decide from where to select the file while using type file in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, html

How to decide from where to select the file while using type file in PHP ?

Like we choose the file from directory, and then we uploads it, but when again go to choose from a directory, it shows that location only from where we have chosen last time.

So, I have to set a location that whenever you will come to select a file you will see a particular location rather than your last location.

Comment: Not my down-vote....Possible duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/q/32080617/715105

Comment: this is your OS functionality. You can't change using php.

Comment: also what do you mean by " I have to set a location that whenever you will come to select a file"? what do you do in your code?

Comment: just do once demo, use type file ...and then at the time run the program , you will choose location right from where you want to choose. And then when you will come again to select file , it will show your last location. So, I dont want location , I want to show a particular location everytime

Answer (score 0):

it is depending on what ever operating system you used.